# Running FFMPEG from Shell Script /bin/sh

Tags: shell, ffmpeg, sh

I am trying to setup a Shell Script to work within an automator watch folder...

Everything works with the exception of the Run Shell Scrip portion...

Essentially when a file shows up in the watch folder, it runs the shell scrip which calls FFMPEG and then will move the file to an archive folder for safe keeping.  However right now automator is telling me everything worked but now file is being created.

I have the Shell set to /bin/sh and Pass input set to as arguments

Here is my script:

```
for f in "$@"
do
name=$(basename "$f")
dir=$(dirname "$f")
ffmpeg -i "$f" -b 250k -strict experimental -deinterlace -vcodec h264 -acodec aac "$dir/mp4/${name%.*}.mp4"
echo "$dir/mp4/${name%.*}.mp4"
done
```

it does echo the correct filename, but does not actually run ffmpeg

I have tried adding `-exec` before it like I have seen in some scripts but still nothing...

Comment: Does the script output anything to stderr?

Comment: Not sure exactly how to use stderr but when I add it to the end of the code, after the echo...It tells me that line 4: ffmpeg command not found

Comment: It runs great in my terminal just can't figure out why it wont work within this shell script

Comment: Off-topic for your question, but your ffmpeg command can be improved. ffmpeg command-line usage questions are better suited at [Super User](http://superuser.com/) (since SO is programming specific). I recommend asking a "how to I improve this command for web playback" question at SU.

Comment: Thanks for the info...I never thought to ask there...

Also got it working after using the stderr which led me to needing the absolute path to ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it is because I am running on a Mac OS X Server but I imagine it is, I had to include the absolute path to ffmpeg...which fixed it

```
for f in "$@"
do
name=$(basename "$f")
dir=$(dirname "$f")
/opt/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -b 250k -strict experimental -deinterlace -vcodec h264 -acodec aac "$dir/mp4/${name%.*}.mp4"
echo "$dir/mp4/${name%.*}.mp4"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

FFmpeg searches STDIN while it is running. This is to allow the user to hit `q` to stop encoding, among other tasks. This could cause a problem with a script. Perhaps to workaround try this:

```
# notice --+
#          |
#          v
ffmpeg -nostdin -i "$f" -b 250k -strict experimental -deinterlace \
  -vcodec h264 -acodec aac "$dir/mp4/${name%.*}.mp4"
```

[mysterious error with ffmpeg on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33205030/#33205173)

Comment: Pretty sure its the most recent version...ffmpeg version 1.1.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  6 2013 10:44:49 with gcc 4.2.1 (GCC) (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)