# Creating forks of `ffmpeg` in loop inside a shell script "loses" some iterations

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ffmpeg

I have a shell script that takes a directory as input, reads all `mp4` files in it and convert them to a `mp3` with `ffmpeg`:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=$1

while read -rd "" file
do
  base=$(basename "$file")
  filename=${base%(*}".mp3"
  ffmpeg -i "$file" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192000 -f mp3 "$filename" &
done < <(find $dir -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.mp4" -print0)

wait

exit 0
```

Currently all these calls to `ffmpeg` are forked because when I leave out the `&` at the end only the first file in converted and the others are ignored.

But this is problematic because somethings this fails on some files error messages like the following:

> path/to/file/file name - with spaces(info)(temp_information).mp4: No such file or directory

All file names normally contain spaces, maybe that is the reason why it fails for some files.

Thus, I have the following questions:

1. When I don't fork the `ffmpeg` calls why is only the first file executed? I expected that the loop waits until the process is finished and then continues with the next iteration.
2. Why is the script unable to find some files (maybe it is a problem of `ffmpeg`)?
3. How to solve all these problems and make the script to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not acknowledging `stdin`

```
ffmpeg -i "$file" -blah -blah -nostdin "$filename" &
```

[shell script ffmpeg stops after 2 jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14882759/#14885970)

To answer the comment:

You should not be forking anyway, FFmpeg already runs in multiple threads to maximize CPU, and you might even suffer
[from thrashing](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29)
by forking it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. This seems to solve the problem. Do you know more about my question 1?

Comment: With the `-nostdin` option it is possible to avoid forking. On each iteration one file is processed. This means everything works as expected now.