# mysterious error with ffmpeg on OSX

Tags: macos, bash, ffmpeg

There seems to be a bug in my bash script, and after a long time I managed to reduce it to this test case:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 | while read blah
do
    echo "$blah"
    ffmpeg -loglevel error -i ./test.jpg -f null /dev/null

done
```

the output from this is

```
/test.jpg
/test.mp4
/test.sh
```

if I remove the ffmpeg invocation, the output becomes this (what I expected):

```
./test.jpg
./test.mp4
./test.sh
```

this seems to occur only when the ffmpeg decoder is activated, as ffmpeg -version doesn't produce the error. Why would ffmpeg affect an unrelated string in this way?

I'm at my wit's end, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FFmpeg is eating your standard input. Do like this instead:

```
find | while read
do
  ffmpeg -nostdin
done
```

[Creating forks of `ffmpeg` in loop inside a shell script "loses" some iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16681623/#16681680)

Comment: magic, that fixed it. I'm still not sure I understand what's going on, but I'll do some reading