# Java execute ffmpeg commands with (pipe) "... -f nut - | ffmpeg -i - ..." just hangs

Tags: java, ffmpeg, process, pipe, exec

I can't get this to run,because java just waits for ffmpeg. But ffmpeg doesn't give an input- nor an error stream. It just runs, but doing nothing.

The output of "System.out.println("command:.."  insert into bash just runs fine as expected.So there is nothing wrong with the ffmpeg syntax.

Here's the code.

```
package mypackage;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

/**
 *
 * @author test
 */
public class ffmpeg_hang {

        /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String INPUT_FILE="/path/to/media";
        String FFMPEG_PATH="/path/to/ffmpegFolder/";

            for(int i=0;(i+4)<40;i+=4){                
            String[] ffmpeg_pipe = new String[]{
                FFMPEG_PATH + "ffmpeg_4.1.1",
                "-ss",(i+""),"-t", "4",             
                "-i", INPUT_FILE,                                        
                "-ac", "1", "-acodec", "pcm_s16le", "-ar", "16000", 
                "-f","nut","-","|",
                FFMPEG_PATH + "ffmpeg_4.1.1",
                "-i","-",
                "-lavfi", "showspectrumpic=s=128x75:legend=disabled:saturation=0:stop=8000",
                "-f","image2pipe","pipe:1"};

            System.out.println("command: "+String.join(" ", ffmpeg_pipe));

            Process p;
            //ffmpe wav->pipe->spectrogra->pipe->java
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(ffmpeg_pipe);


            StringBuilder Boxbuffer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Boxbuffer.append(line);
            }


            System.out.println("ffmpeg errors->> "+Boxbuffer.toString());
            p.waitFor();


            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(p.getInputStream());
            //do stuff with image
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Add -report to both ffmpeg commands and share report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pipe will not be interpreted when passed directly in a command this way, it will be just another argument to the first `ffmpeg` at the beginning of your command. Consider using `/bin/sh -c "command1 | command2"` as wrapper (assuming non-Windows OS...).

Consider adding `-nostdin` to first `ffmpeg` command to avoid a [number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249993/6730571) of [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14866487/6730571) with ffmpeg trying to read stdin when you're not expecting it to (not in second one obviously).

Consider using [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to build complex strings with variables.

Consider using `ProcessBuilder` for easier process creation. Here I'm redirecting errors so they end up to your java process stderr, so you can read your child process's stdout without using a thread. [See alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14165517/6730571)

So here is a suggestion:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String INPUT_FILE = "/path/to/media";
    String FFMPEG_PATH = "/path/to/ffmpegFolder";

    for (int i = 0; (i + 4) < 40; i += 4) {

        String command1 = String.format(
                "%s/ffmpeg_4.1.1 -nostdin -ss %d -t 4 -i '%s' -ac 1 -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 16000 -f nut -",
                FFMPEG_PATH, i, INPUT_FILE);

        String command2 = String.format(
                "%s/ffmpeg_4.1.1 -i - -lavfi showspectrumpic=s=128x75:legend=disabled:saturation=0:stop=8000",
                FFMPEG_PATH);

        Process process = new ProcessBuilder("sh", "-c", command1 + " | " + command2)
                .redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
                .start();

        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(process.getInputStream());
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are blocking on the `stderr` stream being closed. If `ffmpeg` does not close its `stderr` before it exits (and I wouldn't expect it to do that), then your program will just deadlock.

Use `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` with `pb.redirectErrorStream(true);` instead.

It is also a good idea to read the process outputs on a different thread to the one that has called `waitFor();`, otherwise you risk deadlock.